# How can I exclude -999 for one plot in a loop?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
# Make plots.
plot_list = list()
for (i in 1:length(var_list)) {
  p = ggplot(all, aes_string(x = time, y = var_list[i])) +
    geom_line()+
    scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%b %y")+
  plot_list[[i]] = p
}

# create pdf where each page is a separate plot. ,
pdf("figures/output.pdf",  width=7, height=1.5)
for (i in 2:length(var_list)) {
  print(plot_list[[i]])
}
dev.off()
```

This gives me a page of 100 plots or so. But one of the variables in `var_list` has values of -999.

How can I ignore it in the loop?

If I add  `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-999, NA))+` to the code, it messes up the scales of other variables. I only want it to ignore -999 in one of the variables.

Comment: `coord_cartesian()` maybe?  Or use an if statement within the loop to either transform those values or not plot them.

Comment: why not just filter it out from your `all` data.frame?